# How to decode with python base64 code url?

Tags: python, base64, decode

I wanna decode this code

```
maHR0cDovLzUxLjE1LjIwOS45MDo4ODAwL2RhdGEvaW1nL2ZpbGVzLzc2MzU5X3JhY2VzLmpwZw=
```

I tried this code

```
import base64
code = "maHR0cDovLzUxLjE1LjIwOS45MDo4ODAwL2RhdGEvaW1nL2ZpbGVzLzc2MzU5X3JhY2VzLmpwZw="
base64.b64decode(code)
```

and this is what i got

```
b'\x99\xa1\xd1\xd1\xc0\xe8\xbc\xbc\xd4\xc4\xb8\xc4\xd4\xb8\xc8\xc0\xe4\xb8\xe4\xc0\xe8\xe0\xe0\xc0\xc0\xbd\x91\x85\xd1\x84\xbd\xa5\xb5\x9c\xbd\x99\xa5\xb1\x95\xcc\xbc\xdc\xd8\xcc\xd4\xe5}\xc9\x85\x8d\x95\xcc\xb9\xa9\xc1\x9c'
```

Comment: What's the correct decoding?

Comment: Are you sure that that code (`"maH...Zw="`) is a URL? Anyway, the decoded string is neither UTF-8 nor UTF-16.

Comment: I'm sure that it's a URL, I was searching on the internet and I found that this is a urlsafe_b64encode can you please tell me how to decode it, I'm not familiar with python I just install it and trying to decode this code thanks

Comment: That base64 string is not a URL in any of the standard character encoding formats. You can test for yourself here: https://www.base64decode.org/